# Problem: "Pair-end" reads scRNA seq data (Drop-seq)

Tags: scrnaseq, read-mapping

In case of Drop-seq, we have paired end data.

Read 1: Cell code + UMI (unique molecule identifier)

Read 2: The transcript information

But I have a problem/doubt with the sample I am working on.

The sample I am using is the [following](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR6261587) (Check the "Reads" tab).

As you know the Drop-seq is "paired-end", we are expected to see two reads for a spot. Although this sample say paired-end, it has only one read per spot.

For example I can share a link of a different scRNA-seq data where you can properly see two reads for a spot

[Example sample](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR8086553), you need to check the "Reads" tab.

Where I am going wrong?

I asked one of the main authors of the paper. The following is the reply I got :

> I recommend that you download the aligned BAM files that are hosted in
>   the same GEO record. Read 1 is already processed into the cell and UMI
>   barcodes and held as custom tags (XC and XM) in the BAM files. The
>   cells are already barcode-corrected, so if you use those files, your
>   cell barcodes will line up with mine; if you start from FASTQs, they
>   will not. For most aligners, you can just use the BAM file as input to
>   realign. (It has all reads, even those that did not align.)

But I could not find any "XM" or "XC" keywords in the bam file :(

To understand his reply you have to be familiar the [processing steps of the Drop-seq](https://github.com/broadinstitute/Drop-seq/files/2425535/Drop-seqAlignmentCookbookv1.2Jan2016.pdf).

Looks like they have submitted some kind of processed data. I could not figure out how much the data is processed. I am trying to use the data starting at different processing steps but I could not figure out how much the data is processed.

Comment: Where did you even find their BAM files in GEO? I only see the output from CellRanger (UMI counts and such).

Comment: My guess is the authors uploaded BAM files to GEO which have been converted back to fastq in SRA, losing all the extra annotation.

Answer (score 3):

I received the following message from the author of another Drop-seq paper:

> After much conversation with the folks at the SRA, it appears the SRA
>   compression algorithm automatically deletes certain subsets of bam
>   tags and does so in cryptic way (in the sense of not alerting the
>   uploader). Obviously this is going to be an issue for many single cell
>   datasets encoded this way, and I hope the SRA will eventually change
>   their system to accommodate.

If you look at the "Download" tab of the [same page](https://trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/sra/?run=SRR6261587), there now exists a link to download the originally uploaded BAM file.

Alternately, you can use the [SRA AWS tutorial](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/docs/sra-aws-download/) to download the files on that platform.